# Schedule a task every 7 PM

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Hello I want to send some data to server at every 7 PM everyday.For this purpose I called this function in my activity.

```
    private void startTimer() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocTimer.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 1000*60*60*24;
    c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

    }
```

In LocTimer class recieve method I am sending data to server.
But at the first time when activity is loaded startTimer sends the data to server.and after that every 24 hour it sennds data.I am trying to stop sending of the data at first time when activity loaded and send data only at 7PM.

Answer (score 0):

You could set time Alaram Manager to invoke the intent only once instead of repeated times by changing the code in your above method

**This:**

```
 manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

**Into:**

```
manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: He has clearly mentioned in the post that he wants to schedule a task at 7 PM everyday, so using manager.setRepeating in this case is correct.

Comment: yes you are right @TMS its working fine but whenever I start the activity it starts automatically at that time also.And at 7 PM it also triggers.

Comment: Thank you for clearing @TMS If that's the case then could you post the oncreate code of the containing activity?

Comment: In onCreate I am just calling the startTimer(),After closing the activity as soon as I resume it,it sends broadcast and uploads data also,whic I dont wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a change in approach here.

Create a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) that is initiated upon the start of the above activity mentioned in your question (has to be done only once).

This foreground service should contain the alrammanager which fires of an pending intent and/or sends the data to server as scheduled (at 7PM).

Hope this helps !